# How to test animation and settimeout with Qunit and SinonJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinon, qunit

I have this javascript (jQuery) code:

```
DisplayToastMessage: function($alert) {
    $alert.animate({
        "opacity": "1",
        "top": 56
    }, 450);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $alert.fadeOut(300, function () {
            $alert.remove();
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

I need to write unit test using QUnit and SinonJS.
I tried with:

```
function HTMLInjectorAlertHelperTests() {
    return '<div class="modal-inner"><i class="modal-icon icon-check-in-circle"></i><a href="javascript:;" class="modal-close do-close-overlay"><i class="icon-x"></i></a><div class="modal-row"><p><span><strong>Emergency contanct updated</strong></span></p></div></div>';
}

QUnit.test('DisplayToastMessages - testing animation', function (assert) {
        var $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
        $fixture.append(HTMLInjectorAlertHelperTests());

        var $modal = $fixture.find(".modal-inner");

        var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

        AlertHelper.DisplayToastMessage($modal);

        clock.tick(500);

        assert.ok($modal.css('opacity') == 1, "Opacity is 1");

        clock.restore();
    });
```

And I think that animation is successfully tested.
After that I started with test for setTimeout function without any success:

```
QUnit.test('DisplayToastMessages - testing alert removal', function (assert) {
    var $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
    $fixture.append(HTMLInjectorAlertHelperTests());

    var $modal = $fixture.find(".modal-inner");

    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

    AlertHelper.DisplayToastMessage($modal);

    clock.tick(5760);

    assert.ok($modal.css('opacity') == 1, "Opacity is 1");

    clock.restore();
});
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong and how to test that element is removed from DOM?